# Need darker shadow on UILabel

Tags: iphone, uilabel, shadow

I've creating a Label with a shadow:

```
#define TITLE_FONT_SIZE 22.0f

titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:TITLE_FONT_SIZE];
titleLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
titleLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
titleLabel.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;  
titleLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
```

The label is on a crossfading image background.
Because of the white, sometimes it's hard to read on lighter backgrounds. And the more I increase the radius, the less dark it gets....
Is it possible to make the shadow darker or make the label 'pop-out' more?
Any other advice that would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done to solve the same problem is use two labels stacked on top of each other. The top label is the regular text color - white in your case. The bottom label is offset one or two pixels and it's text color and shadow color are set to the same value - black in your case. This gives at least a sharp shadow directly beneath the main label and still lets it soften for a nice shadow effect.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I actually drew 4 extra labels, so it looks like the white text has a black outline and each label still has the shadow resulting in a darker shadow overall. Thanx for the hint.